# Usar Operador IN en procedimiento almacenado Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este código en php que me ha estado funcionando bien:

```php
//$_REQUEST['cods']='[3,5,8,9]'
$productos=substr($_REQUEST['cods'], 1, -1); //'3,5,8,9'
$mysqli->query("update tabla set estado='x' where cod in ($productos)") or die($mysqli->error);
```

Pero quiero hacerlo con un procedimiento almacenado:

```php
$mysql->query("CALL Actualizar('x',$productos)") or die($mysql->error);
```

Y este es el procedimiento:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`base`@`%` PROCEDURE `Actualizar`(IN `est` CHAR(1), IN `codis` TEXT)
    NO SQL
update tabla set estado=est where cod in (codis)$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Pero no me ha funcionado, si paso `$productos` sin comillas me sale un error de que estoy pasando más parámetros de los que debería al procedimiento almancenado (`Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE base.Actualizar; expected 2, got 5`), y si lo paso con comillas solo se ejecuta el primer número, y los otros 3 no se ejecutan (no sale error, simplemente no se realiza el update para el 5,8 y 9), quisiera saber cómo manejar esto. PD:La columna `cod` es un `smallint` pero puse `text` en el procedimiento porque estoy mandando una cadena.

Comment: Por favor incluye los mensajes completos de error, no los resumas.

Comment: Ya lo actualicé: Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE base.Actualizar; expected 2, got 5

Comment: Probaste ponerle corchetes al array que pasas cómo parametro

Comment: Si lo paso con corchetes y sin comillas me sale error de sintaxys, y si paso: $mysql->query("CALL Actualizar('c','$_REQUEST[cods]')") or die($mysql->error); Se ejecuta pero no cambia ninguna fila, ni siquiera la del cod 3

Comment: @ArturoRodas ¿Que versión de MySQL utilizas?

Comment: La versión es 5.7.20

Comment: Tiene varias opciones, comento un par de ellas: consultas dinámicas [Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) y [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). Ver un ejemplo ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3d7b1519e880c4f74782012ee08d1398)) usando `FIND_IN_SET` que puede darle alguna idea. Lo siento, pero la documentación está en Inglés.